# Place form fields horizontally using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap

How do we place form fields horizontally using Twitter Bootstrap

I tried below HTML code. But it shows one by one like below

- **First Name** - Text Box
- **Last Name** - Text Box

  **Search**

  ```
  <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="first">First Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" id="first" placeholder="firstname">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="lastname">Last Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">              
          <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  ```

I want First Name and Last Name should be placed horizontally in first line and in next line Search Button.

Like this

- **First Name** - Text Box          **Last Name** - Text Box

  **Search**

Answer (score 8):

Add `inline` class to First name, Last name `control-group` div:

```
<div class="control-group inline">
```

**CSS**

```
.inline {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GgSRN/

Answer (score 7):

try this

```
    <form class="form-group form-inline">
      <label class="control-label" for="first">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="first" placeholder="firstname">
      <label class="control-label" for="lastname">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">

      <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

check [bootstrap inline Form](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#forms)
 it will be good to go as you said.

Comment: i have updated my answer... i think it will work for you as you said

Comment: i have updated the link, they moved there home to different domain due to new version of bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS in a separate file to style your html. I'd personally wrap them in a `<div class="row">` using Bootstrap and use one of those for each 'row' you want to create.